# Get IOS notification in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm currently writing an app in react native (for the sake of learning) where you can set an alarm, and when the time comes,  it should display a notification, even if the app is not active (user closed the iOS  app)

What do you recommend? I'm just thinking about how to do this, and I really don't know how.

Comment: Check out the `react-native-notifications` library from Wix. https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications

Comment: use this lib. "react-native-firebase": "^4.3.8"

Comment: give me sent your code , which lib. use for notification